# kdb+ unable to use csv data after import

Tags: csv, kdb

I'm trying to load csv data to test some kdb+ q functions I've written.  After loading the data to a table and flipping one row into a dictionary, I have unexpected commas in the referenced data.

I created a very simple csv file called testdata.txt:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

I load the csv like so:

```
td: ("JJJJJJJ";1#",") 0: `:data/testdata.txt
```

Results:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g 
--------------------
1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

I then extract one row and flip it to a dictionary:

```
tdic: flip 1#td
```

So far so good:

```
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
d| 4
e| 5
f| 6
g| 7
```

Then I try to reference one of the items in the dictionary and I have a comma preceding the value.

```
q)tdic `a
,1
```

Due to the comma my data is not usable for any testing purposes, at least if I flip it to a dictionary.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong as I've not seen this issue documented anywhere.

Comment: Worth noting also that `#` creates lists, e.g. see `1#1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the types of each entry in `tdic` you will see they are actually lists (positive integers):

```
type each tdic
a| 7
b| 7
c| 7
d| 7
e| 7
f| 7
g| 7
```

You could instead use indexing to get atoms instead of lists:

```
show tdic:td[0]
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
d| 4
e| 5
f| 6
g| 7

type each tdic
a| -7
b| -7
c| -7
d| -7
e| -7
f| -7
g| -7
```

The output is no longer a list:

```
q)tdic`a
1
```